# Getting CORS error inspite of cors configuration in the server

Tags: javascript, angular, socket.io

socket.io newbie here...

My socket.io server is this

```
var cors = require('cors')
const http = require('http');
const socketio = require('socket.io');

// create http server with node
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.end("I am connected");
});

// piggyback the http server
const io = socketio(server, {
    origin: "https://localhost:4200",
    methods: ["GET","POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["content-type"]
});


io.on('connection', (socket,req) => {
    socket.emit('banner','Welcome to the socket io server');
    socket.on('message', (msg) => {
        console.log(msg);
    });
});

server.listen(8000);
```

The client is angular application running at https://localhost:4200.
A js file inside it is my socket.io client, which looks like this

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:8000');
socket.on('connect', (data) => {
  socket.on('banner', (message)=> {
    console.log(message);
  });

  socket.emit('message', {data:'Client is connected'});
});
```

I keep seeing this error in the browser's console

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OMcLBLw. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200
```

Any clue what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the **cors** package is only supposed to be used as Express middleware. You don't seem to be using Express, nor the cors module (your code just imports it on line 1 and then completely ignores it).

According to [this reference](https://gist.github.com/balupton/3696140) you can set headers directly on the response header of a Node http server as well though. So before "I am connected" you could try:

```js
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```